# TensorFlow Distributed training using tf.Supervisor stalls when running init_op

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I'm trying to get some simple distributed training code working using TensorFlow r0.12.1 based on the [example on this page from the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/distributed/). However, I'm having issues with my distributed sessions never returning.

My cluster specification is as follows, and I am running both the ps and worker processes on the same server:

```
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({
    'ps': ['localhost:2222'],
    'worker': ['localhost:2223', 'localhost:2224']
})
```

Using this, my ps process is as follows:

```
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="ps")
server.join()
```

And my two workers attempt to train a simple network using MNIST, and are launched using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` or `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`:

```
TASK_INDEX = <0 or 1>
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=TASK_INDEX)

with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
    global_step = tf.Variable(0)

    train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(task_index == 0),
                         init_op=init_op,
                         summary_op=summary_op,
                         global_step=global_step)

with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
    step = 0
    batch_sz = 50
    iters = 55000 / batch_sz
    while not sv.should_stop() and step < iters:
        _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict={x: mnist.train.images[step*batch_sz:(step+1)*batch_sz],
                                                               y_: mnist.train.labels[step*batch_sz:(step+1)*batch_sz]})

# Ask for all the services to stop.
sv.stop()
```

Unfortunately, my code appears to freeze on the call to `with sv.managed_session(server.target)`. Further diagnosis shows that the troublesome line is in fact the call to `session_manager.wait_for_session` which is initiated from the chief worker and, within this, the line 235 of `tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py`:

```
sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
```

So it seems like the whole process is stalling when attempting to run the initialisation operation, but does not produce any error messages. Regular training (not via tf.Supervisor) works fine on the same system, and so it seems unlikely it is installation / driver issues.

Is there any reason why the process should stall when running `init_op`? Is there something I am missing about how to properly use `tf.Supervisor`?

Comment: A follow up: here is a slightly cleaned-up version of the above with the same behaviour on my system (freezes at init_op): https://github.com/kencoken/tf-distribute-test/blob/master/serve.py

Comment: that typically happens when it can't connect to the parameter server. It will hang indefinitely until connection is able to be established. I would check that connection is possible to establish to the target host/port (using netcat or telnet). Also `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` may be useful

Comment: Thanks very much for this! This does indeed seem to be a good hypothesis. I'm running on localhost though, and have confirmed that ports are open using netcat while running. What's more, if I run with `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` and `GRPC_TRACE=all`, it looks like messages are being sent back and forth between the parameter server and workers... any other ideas for how to check more deeply in the code where things are getting stuck?

Comment: what is `init_op` doing? You could try to narrow down things by trying with an example where `init_op` is a no-op (try on network with no variables), or pass a custom init_op that does nothing.

Comment: That's great advice @YaroslavBulatov – thanks so much! Somehow the code started running though, so suggests it may have been RPC issues after all. Would love to help make the failure behaviour of the RPC a little more transparent – perhaps that's a discussion that can be moved to the TF repo though!